# IIS7 Rewrite Rule not working

Tags: iis-7, .net-3.5, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have created a this rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ImageRedirect" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^(.*)/(.*)/" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.lrgimages.com/ImageRewrite.aspx?=img={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I keep getting a 404.0 message like the rule is not working or IIS is not picking it up. In the test parttern section for the rule, the pattern tests fine. If I go directly to the http://www.lrgimages.com/ImageRewrite.aspx that page loades, but not when I try: http://www.lrgimages.com/TestImage

any thoughts?

Update: I figured it out. It does not take into acount hte http://www.DomainName.com when rewriting a url. Redirects work this way since htat is what is is really doing. I am used to other rewrite engines not taking into account the http://www.DomainName.com . Thanks all you lead me in the right direction.

Comment: as mentioned below that rule isn't going to match your test url, try a rule of "^TestImage" to see if the module is loaded at all.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting a 404.4 message..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "/TestImage" matches `^(.*)/(.*)/` ...

Comment: Does the rewrite engine take into account the "http://www.lrgimage.com" when the expressions is checked? When I put the "http://www.lrgimages.com/TestImage" into the tester I see 3 matches so I thought the engine would parse out the items for me.

Comment: @DDiVita most ignore the domain name and only function on the path after that. There's quite a good tutorial here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/